# Dynamic number of WHERE conditions in Google Sheet query function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building  a spreadsheet that can be used to import and then filter wireshark capture .csv's.  The idea is - you import the .csv into the second tab, and on the first tab you are able to display the data based on a number of include/exclude filters. Here is a dummy sheet for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17TtZHRiXCaH1XClq5SGRdIuyLZnMOrl6Ygrbfo9BbfM/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see in the spreadsheet, I have four possible "include" values and four possible "exclude" values, each being determined by selection of a drop down-list.  The intention is for the QUERY() function in cell A6 to display the data based on these filters.
[Example of the filter at work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP1gR.png)

I know how to use WHERE to do it for a single filter condition:

> =query('Import CSV Here'!1:349,"select * where ("&B4&"="&B2&")")

And how to do it for multiple filter conditions:

> =query('Import CSV Here'!1:349,"select * where ("&B4&"="&B2&") and ("&C4&"="&C2&")" )

What I can't figure out is how to write the QUERY function so that it only factors in a WHERE condition for filter columns that aren't blank (and therefore have been actively populated from their drop down menus).   Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `where G is not null or H is not null` or some other similar form of `is not null`"

Comment: just tried using `
where ("&B6&" is not null and "&B8&"="&B6&"")`

Comment: I believe you may have the intent of the query function off a bit,  It is intended to return multiple rows. You don't normally use individual cells in the statement unless you are checking all the rows against a common value out of a cell  So =query('Import CSV Here'!A1:Z349 , "select * where B is not null") will return every row where B has a value and include the first row as a header regardless of the value of B i that first row.  Try simplifying to that and see what results you get. Then try another single test and look at those results. Get more complicated after testing the simple ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each filter condition in an if clause and use put something that evaluates to true if it is blank.

```
=query(
  'Import CSV Here'!1:349,
  "select * WHERE " &
     IF(ISBLANK(B2), "1=1", B4 & "=" & B2) &
     " and " & IF(ISBLANK(C2), "1=1", C4 & "=" & C2) )
```

Comment: this returns a parse error.  can you use an if function in a query like this?

Comment: Sorry you cannot, the string of the if is calculate outside and then all the parts concatenated, see my updated answer

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Good lesson for me on concatencation... thanks!

Comment: One more question on this...  for the example spreadsheet I linked to, I purposely used arbitrary strings without any special characters in the data table.  I did this because I wanted to figure out the dynamic conditions first.  In reality though, the values MAC_ADDRESS and DESTINATION values have "." and ":" characters in them - this breaks the formula because the Query can't parse the strings.  I obviously can't manually escape the characters since they are chosen from a drop-down menu.  Is there a proper syntax for this that will solve this problem?

Comment: You can just add sinle quotation marks into the concatenation e.g. `...B4 & "='" & B2 & "'")...`